# Can't find the error in my SQL syntax - PHP (check manual for syntax?)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html, phpmyadmin

### The Problem:

I am trying to subtract 0.05 from the variable cash_amount in my database called users, and i am calling this file by ajax but nothing is occurring. To fix this, i opened the file in my browser and i got this error:

### The Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

### The Code:

***PHP:***

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPass";
$dbname = "myDBname";
$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];

// Create connection

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

// You must enter the user's id here. /\

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid
$_SESSION['cash_amount'] -= 0.05;
$newAmount = $cash_amount - 0.05;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = $newAmount WHERE id = $userid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result)
{
   echo "5 cents have been subtracted!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
   session_start();
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

***Javascript/AJAX:***

```
function countdownEnded() {
    //make serverscreen dissapear
        document.getElementById('serverScreenWrapper').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('serverScreenWrapper').style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById("cashOutNumTwo").style.right = '150%';
        document.getElementById("cashOutNumOne").style.right = '150%';
//start Timer
        setInterval(gameTimer.update, 1000);
//make player move again
        socket.emit('4');
        socket.emit('6');
//make game appear
        document.getElementById('gameAreaWrapper').style.opacity = 1;
//play sound
        document.getElementById('spawn_cell').play();
//cut 5 cents from account - php function
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php',
        data: { },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

### My Database:

My table is called users and its inside of the DB casball_accounts.

Here is the format:

id | first_name | last_name | email | password | cash_amount | 4 in between | hash | active

### Conclusion:

I am pretty confused on why my php code isn't working, I have already tried searching for a fix and i found the words "SQL Injection" but I still didn't find the error. I am advanced at JS but a beginner to PHP, so please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that `id` and `cash_amount` are correctly found in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = cash_amount - 0.05 WHERE id = $userid";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly so this is working, but for some reason i have to log out and then back in when using it to update the amount, do you know why?

Comment: Hi, logout of what?

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it, i want to label you as the correct answer but you are a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the query and do

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = cash_amount - 0.05 WHERE id = $userid";
```

But to avoid the possibility of SQL Injection I would suggets also changing the code to use a parameterised and bound query like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = cash_amount - 0.05 WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're interpolating data into the query, which, if that is what you want, you go with Mostafa's answer and put quotes around those values in case they're malformed. Which also means you have to check to see if they're legitimate values before putting them into the query.

However, they may also be subject to user input somewhere up the line, so do use PDO's prepared statements.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = :newAmount WHERE id = :userid";
$conn = $conn->prepare($sql, [PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY]);
$conn->execute([':newAmount' => $newAmount, ':userid' => $userid])
```

...should take care of the issue. But making sure you have what tyou think you have can prevent a lot of red herrings.

Comment: Thanks, but now the script isn't working at all, the page is just not opening

Comment: `mysqli_` also has prepared statements, and that would be a lot easier than changing an app from `mysqli_` to PDO

Comment: So what do i do? Should i go with Mustafa's answer?

Comment: This would also destroy the `$conn` variable for later use. I know this code only uses it once, but it is hust bad example code

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error complains there's a problem near `''` which means there is nothing following the point where it gets confused. I.e., it gets confused at the end of the query.

If `$userid` is blank, your SQL query will be

```
UPDATE users SET cash_amount = ... WHERE id =
```

This is clearly wrong syntax, because `=` requires two operands.

You need to make sure your `$userid` has a non-blank value.

The suggestions in other answers try to work around the issue by using quotes or query parameters, but the real problem is that you don't check that `$userid` has a value before you use it.

Comment: The other comment actually fixed it, but now the file isn't being called from AJAX, but when i put the link in the browser it works.

Comment: Unless you can connect the AJAX problem to your SQL update query, then it's a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = '$newAmount' WHERE id = '$userid'";
```

instead

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = $newAmount WHERE id = $userid";
```

Comment: and hope no one manages to get a string like `0' OR 1=1` into $userid